# Poincaré's last geometric theorem

Tags: celestial-mechanics, differential-equations

Which problem in celestial mechanics led Poincaré to his conjecture about fixed points of area preserving maps of the annulus to itself? I believe he was working on some differential equations. What was the problem and what was the differential equations he was working on?

Answer (score 3):

Poincaré was studying [the circular restricted three-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem#Circular_restricted_three-body_problem), where two bodies in a binary system revolve around their barycenter and a third test mass moves in some orbit around them. Birkhoff acknowledges this in his proof of the theorem, [*Proof of Poincaré's Geometric Theorem*](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1913-014-01/S0002-9947-1913-1500933-9/S0002-9947-1913-1500933-9.pdf). Specifically, Poincaré was looking to prove that this third body may have periodic orbits.

John Franks is quoted in Steve Nadis' [*A History in Sum*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4e29AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=poincare+last+geometric+theorem+three-body+problem&source=bl&ots=oY4qbR6eF-&sig=qUN_-waF9TInAp8jv0Hr-PwDH6E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0so7buvLQAhVjJsAKHX88BGQQ6AEITzAJ#v=onepage&q=poincare%20last%20geometric%20theorem%20three-body%20problem&f=false) as describing the annulus as "a two-dimensional slice of three-dimensional space". If a planet moves from a point on the annulus to the rest of the space and then back, this must be a fixed point, and there must therefore be periodicity. In fact, Poincaré's theorem states that if there is one such point there must be *a second* point; one of the two describes the third body.

Poincaré was not considering any differential equations, but instead the [*Jacobi integral*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_integral) $C_J$, which here [takes the form](http://www.math.cornell.edu/%7Etemplier/junior/final_paper/Christopher_Schlom-Poincare_map_restricted.pdf)
$$C_J=-\frac{2H}{m}=-\left(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2\right)+\left(x^2+y^2\right)+2\left(\frac{1-\mu}{r_1}+\frac{\mu}{r_2}\right)$$
for Hamiltonian $H$, test mass $m$, coordinates $(x,y)$, masses of main bodies $1-\mu$ and $\mu$, and distances to those bodies $r_1$ and $r_2$.